Share sass variables from app to lib in nx
I'm in the process of migrating my project to an Nx monorepo setup. My workspace consists of multiple applications, each with its own distinct theme, and several shared UI libraries that rely on SASS variables for styling.
Project Structure:

Apps:

app-theme-light

app-theme-dark

(Each app has its own set of SASS variables for theming)



Libraries:

ui-components

shared-utils

(UI libraries use SASS for styling and need access to SASS variables)




Objective: I want to keep the SASS variables scoped within each app to maintain distinct themes. However, I also need the shared UI libraries to access these app-specific SASS variables for consistent styling across components.
Is there a way to share the variable file from app to library ?
I tried to add the path for variable file like this.
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@gx/style-variables": ["apps/my-app/src/styles/style-variables.scss"]
    }
  }
}

I coudn't access the file from library this way. I am expecting a better way to acces my variable file inside app scope from the library.


Typically the scss files in the lib would declare defaults for these variables, and they would be overridden as part of the build process. By the way, you should consider if sass variables is the right choice here. This kind of thing is far more idiomatic to implement as CSS variables, which would mean you do not need to rebuild the core lib CSS for every application, since CSS variables are at runtime. Compile time injection doesn't really gain you anything, apart from unnecessary complexity...
